# Generate unique randoms when we cannot store previous generated randoms

Tags: c#, arrays, math, random

We have an array (of strings for example). The size of this array is not fixed.

Now, our machine, selects an element of this array every 3 minutes and shows us. The problem is we don't have a memory to store the elements we have picked before, and every 3 minutes when we select from this array we would like the elements to first cover up the whole array and then they are free to repeat, but they should not repeat before every element has been picked up once.

We don't have memory to store the elements picked but we can get the MinutesInDay variable (how many minutes have passed in the day). I believe something could be done using this variable.

Comment: Language? Do the elements have to be randomly chosen, or is sequential OK? I haven't fully thought it through, but I suspect this could be done fairly easily with Reactive programming and Observables, especially if sequential access is OK.

Comment: I assume that there's some requirement for pseudorandomness, since you're using the `random` tag. Otherwise, just show the first element, then the second, etc. How random does the sequence need to be? No obvious pattern to a casual observer? Or something much stronger than that?

Comment: Does the array change size during this process? If not, you could just shuffle the array then choose items in the new order. When you reach the end, shuffle again and display from the beginning again. Or, you could just store a bit-array of `1` for displayed and `0` for not yet displayed. This would take very little memory compared to the strings.

Comment: Sir @RobertLewis Can it be done with c#. When 3 minutes occur, there is no possible memory / no possible way to remember what was picked last time. What we only can get is the current time of the machine.

Comment: Sir @MarkDickinson, when 3 minutes occur the machine cannot even remember the index of the element that was picked up last time. It's just like a program X which is run every 3 minutes by some other program and the only parameter it can supply to X is the current Time, and we expect X to give us unique random index of the array.

Comment: Sir @RoryDaulton, yes the array does change size. And it's just like a program X triggered by program Y every 3 minutes. And Y can only supply to X the currentTime variable. The system cannot remember the index of the last element that was chosen. And we expect X to not give us duplicates until all elements are covered. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to keep an array containing strings that have been chosen at random (or pointers to chosen strings), and to remove strings from the array of available strings as they are chosen. In this way the number of strings stored will always be only one larger than the number of strings that you start with; one larger because in each iteration the chosen string is copied into the `chosen` array before it is removed from the `available` array. When the `available` array is empty, the contents of `chosen` can be copied back to `available`, and the cycle can repeat.

The OP did not specify a language, but here is Lua script as a proof of concept:

```lua
math.randomseed(os.time())

available = { "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4", "String 5" }
chosen = {}

for count = 1, 3 * #available do

   -- Choose random member from available
   local i = math.random(1, #available)
   print(available[i])

   -- Add member to chosen
   table.insert(chosen, available[i])

   -- Remove from available
   table.remove(available, i)

   -- Reset and repeat
   if #available == 0 then
      available = chosen
      chosen = {}
      print()
   end
end
```

Here is the output from a couple of sample runs:

```
> dofile("unique_randoms_43019470.lua")
String 5
String 3
String 2
String 1
String 4

String 4
String 3
String 5
String 2
String 1

String 5
String 1
String 4
String 3
String 2

> dofile("unique_randoms_43019470.lua")
String 1
String 4
String 2
String 3
String 5

String 1
String 2
String 3
String 5
String 4

String 4
String 1
String 5
String 2
String 3
```

Here is a C version that works in place on an array, which could easily be extended to work with dynamically allocated arrays. This code removes a random member of `available` and moves it in the array to one past the remaining available strings, shrinking the size of the available pool. The output is comparable to the Lua version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define START_SIZE  5

void remove_available(size_t ndx, char **list, size_t list_sz);

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    size_t available_sz = START_SIZE;
    char *available[START_SIZE];

    available[0] = "String 1";
    available[1] = "String 2";
    available[2] = "String 3";
    available[3] = "String 4";
    available[4] = "String 5";

    for (size_t count = 0; count < 3*START_SIZE; count++) {

        /* Choose random member from available */
        size_t i = rand() % available_sz;
        puts(available[i]);

        remove_available(i, available, available_sz);
        --available_sz;

        /* Reset and repeat */
        if (available_sz == 0) {
            available_sz = START_SIZE;
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Remove element at ndx and move to end of available segment */
void remove_available(size_t ndx, char **av, size_t av_sz)
{
    --av_sz;
    char *temp = av[ndx];

    for (size_t i = ndx; i < av_sz; i++) {
        av[i] = av[i+1];
    }
    av[av_sz] = temp;
}
```

Comment: @Sanjay-- I saw in the comments that you mentioned C#. I don't use C#, but I have added a C version of the code in my answer that may be closer to what you are looking for.